# Detection of two different frequencies using oscilloscope

Tags: frequency

My signal has two different frequencies: 660kHz and 80 MHz.

How can I make the oscilloscope just display the 660kHZ frequency? Right now all I see is 80MHz.

Thank you

Comment: Engage filtering and reduce the timescale.

Comment: Some oscilloscopes have low-pass-filters available to activate, just for situations like yours.

Comment: you do not see anything other than the 80MHz signal? nothing at all?

Comment: Send a picture to see the signals.

Comment: Might be a stupid request but try zooming out on the time scale to see the 660kHz signal. If you're just seeing a few cycles of the 80 MHz bits, you're not going to see the 660 kHz signal. Also, use the FFT function if you have it on your scope, because that offers a larger dynamic range.

Comment: @hatsunearu That's an answer, should go into the _answer_ box so it can be vetted and accepted

Comment: What’s the proportion between both frequencies?

Comment: Is this a modulated signal?

Comment: Use a filter (build one) or use the fft on the scope if it has one

Answer (score 1):

Might be a stupid request but try zooming out on the time scale to see the 660kHz signal. If you're just seeing a few cycles of the 80 MHz bits, you're not going to see the 660 kHz signal. Also, use the FFT function if you have it on your scope, because that offers a larger dynamic range.

If this doesn't work, you need to filter your signal. Using the 20/40MHz filter on your scope (most scopes should have this), which may help enough. If that doesn't work, a discrete filter may have to be built. Since 660kHz and 80MHz is far apart, a simple 1 pole RC filter will probably be enough.